# Discover each product url

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFqm1.png

Need to extract all product urls,tried this. Couldn't get most of them

url = "https://alcohaul.sg/"

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("a");
var myarray = []
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++){
var nametext = x[i].textContent;
var cleantext = nametext.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
var cleanlink = x[i].href;
myarray.push([cleantext,cleanlink]);
};
function make_table() {
    var table = '<table><thead><th>Name</th><th>Links</th></thead><tbody>';
   for (var i=0; i<myarray.length; i++) {
            table += '<tr><td>'+ myarray[i][0] + '</td><td>'+myarray[i][1]+'</td></tr>';
    };
 
    var w = window.open("");
w.document.write(table); 
}
make_table()
```

Comment: Are the products dynamically loaded when you scroll the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "all product URLs", you're referring to the products which are visible on the main page, yes?

I visited the page in my browser and logged my network traffic. The browser made various HTTP GET requests to some REST APIs. One of them has the endpoint `api/newarrival`, the response of which contains all the product information for the products on the main page - in JSON. All you have to do is imitate that HTTP GET request. This API seems pretty lenient - no request headers required, and not even any query-string parameters. However, this also means that you can expect the response of this API to change with time as newer "new arrivals"... arrive.

```
def main():

    import requests

    url = "https://alcohaul.sg/api/newarrival"

    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()

    base_url = "https://alcohaul.sg/products/{}"

    for product in response.json():
        print(base_url.format(product["slug"]))

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
https://alcohaul.sg/products/absolut-vodka-blue-70cl
https://alcohaul.sg/products/campari-70cl
https://alcohaul.sg/products/botanist-gin-70cl
https://alcohaul.sg/products/strangelove-premium-light-tonic-pack-4-x-180ml
https://alcohaul.sg/products/strangelove-premium-indian-tonic-no-8-pack-4-x-180ml
https://alcohaul.sg/products/strangelove-premium-coastal-tonic-pack-4-x-180ml
https://alcohaul.sg/products/strangelove-premium-lo-cal-double-ginger-beer-pack-4-x-300ml
...
```